# Pentaho - How to add Saiku Analytics component on dashboard using CDE

Tags: data-visualization, pentaho, saiku

I have a community edition of Pentaho and also installed 'Saiku Analytics' and 'Community dashboard editor' CDE.

How can I add an interactive report on dashboard and have this dashboard available for a particular user.

Answer (score 2):

First you save the query that you want to show in you CDE, in the Saiku component on the top is a disk image, then on the CDE, at the component panel you add a Saiku widget and the configure the properties. You will use the same file that you saved on the Saiku component.

Comment: Thanks @shau for your response, we will try this when get back to this project and hopefully it will work.